# C# access different Settings

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

In my app, I have added 3 different *.settings files. Upon a selection, I want to use different App settings, so I need to change the default.

Normally we access it via

```
Settings.Default
```

How can I set different ones? I already have created the files

Comment: It depends to where you have added setting files. For example, assuming you have added `Settings1.setting` in `Properties` folder, then you can access it by `Properties.Settings1.Default`

Comment: [Manage application settings (.NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet) ( `Use customized settings files -> Project Designer`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends to where you have added setting files. For example, assuming you have added `Settings1.setting` in `Properties` folder, then you can access it in code through `Properties.Settings1.Default`.

The `.settings` files use a custom tool (`SettingsSingleFileGenerator`) which follows Visual Studio's standards to generate namespace for the file. To use a different namespace for the generated code, you can put the file in a custom folder hierarchy which will be used as namespace of the class, or you can easily set the `Custom Tool Namespace` of the `.settings` file.

You can open the underlying `.Designer.cs` of your `.settings` file and and you see the namespace, class name, and the `Default` property which returns a single instance of your `Settings1` class (singleton).