# What assembly to get application properties?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have example code that looks like this, but I can't figure out where assembly to include to get `Properties` ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ScreenSizeEntity
{
    class ScreenSize
    {
        public void Resize(Form scrn)
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Normal(scrn);
            }
            else
            {
                Maximise(scrn);
            }
        }
        public void Maximise(Form scrn, bool MaximiseOverride = false)
        {
            scrn.Text = "";
            scrn.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            scrn.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            scrn.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
            scrn.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
            if (!MaximiseOverride)
                Properties.Settings.Default.IsMaximised = true;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            scrn.Invalidate();
            Application.DoEvents();
            scrn.TopMost = true;
            scrn.Activate();
        }

 ...
```

Comment: Sorry,are you asking to get the properties of a type? If so you may want to look into ```System.Reflection``` and get the type of whatever you're looking to get the properties from and do this: ```typeof(Form).GetProperties()```.

Comment: What do you think 'Properties' is? can provide a link to a documentation page

Comment: @SylasCoker This looks like a question regarding `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` etc calling from a separate class.

Comment: You need to use the right namespace. Take a look at this post: [Access Settings classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71833235/3110834)